# Error while trying to run Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to execute script in another Azure VM

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error while trying to run Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to run a script to download file in different VM from azure blob storage. The az module is installed in all the VM's involved here.

```
Value[0]        :
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       :
Value[1]        :
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : New-AzStorageContext : The term 'New-AzStorageContext' is not recognized as
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.8\Downloads\s
cript10.ps1:3 char:19
+ $StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName csd1u1prdo ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-AzStorageContext:String) []
   , CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Get-AzStorageBlobContent : The term 'Get-AzStorageBlobContent' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.CPlat.Core.RunCommandWindows\1.1.8\Downloads\s
cript10.ps1:5 char:1
+ Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob "test.txt" -Container $containerName - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-AzStorageBlobContent:String
   ) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Status          : Succeeded
Capacity        : 0
Count           : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that haven't loaded the Azure PowerShell module. When you install the Cmdlets you will also get a new shortcut "Microsoft Azure Powershell" which will automatically load the module for you (and make the Cmdlets available).

The best way to use Azure PowerShell cmdlets is to start the Azure PowerShell directly from the generated shortcut by the installer. Or use the Import-Module command to import Azure PowerShell module.

For detailed instructions, read this: How to install and configure Azure Power Shell module - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/